# Two buttons appear when use setRightBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I use the code below to customise the right barbutton on the navigation bar:

```
UIBarButtonItem *bb = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_daohangrightbar_1"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(clickRightBtnEvent:)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:bb];
```

But I get the result as below:

[image]

It seems that both the custom barButton and the system's default buttons get displayed. FYI, no button is shown before I add my custom button.HOw do make the default button disappear and show only my custom button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try creaing a custom button with the image provided and initialize the bar button with customview and provide that button as custom view.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height);

UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
[btn setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(clickRightButtonEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *bb = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:bb];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `initWithCustomView` from `UIBarButtonItem` with a `UIImageView` containing your `UIImage`.